# Query speed slow down after change to utf8mb4

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, mysql-python

I'm a newbie of Mysql and AWS. 
Now what I doing is to transfer the old database table to new table in other database.
the old database and new database are in the same EC2 server. I write a code using mysqlclient to do that on the other server, it also an EC2 server. the speed of sync data is 4 records per second last Friday. But I found an other problem about storing emoji, so I change the database to encoding in utf8mb4.

```html
alter database django_database character set utf8mb4 collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

But on Monday,when I ssh to the server running sync code, I found the speed of sync data turn to  4 records per 9 seconds. 
I have tried restart MySQL service, reboot MySQL server, reboot the server where my code running on. I also tried run the code on the other EC2 instance. But it still the slow speed. And I don't know how to find what cause that. I also tried to skip-name-resolve, but it still too slow. Hope someone has the answer of it. Or tell me how to find analyze it. Thanks for all the people who finished reading my question.

Answer (score 0):

I found what caused that! I use the t2.medium. When I feel the speed is fast,  the instance use the CPU surplus credit. And I found it became slow when the credit ran out.